# Laravel Voyager How to make a custom field translated?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

How to make a custom field translated? 
I add a custom field `id_post` to the table `categories`  and display it with BREAD. 
But translations are not included in the table `translations`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;
class Category extends Model
{
    use Translatable;
    protected $translatable = ['name', 'slug','id_post'];
}
```